# Chrome extension not automatically activating on new tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I open a new tab, the extension won't activate until I click on it. From that point on I can refresh the tab and the extension will stay active, but deactivates again if I navigate to a different domain. I want it to be always active like some other extensions seem to be. How can I accomplish this? Here is the code:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Test"
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                css: ["input[type='password']"]
            })],
            actions: [
                new chrome.declarativeContent.RequestContentScript({
                    js: ['main.js']
                })
            ]
        }]);
    });
});
```

main.js

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('delay', function(data) { 
    alert(data.delay || 60);
});
```

popup.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      input {
        width: 80px;
      }
      button {
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" id="delaySeconds"></input>
    <button id="setDelay" type="button">Delay (seconds)</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
let delaySeconds = document.getElementById('delaySeconds');
let setDelay = document.getElementById('setDelay');
let script = ['alert(',')'];
let tab = undefined;

chrome.storage.sync.get('delay', function(data) {
    delaySeconds.setAttribute('value', data.delay || 60);
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        tab = tabs[0].id;
    });
});

setDelay.onclick = function() {
    let delay = {
        "delay": delaySeconds.value
    };
    chrome.storage.sync.set(delay, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            tab, {
                code: script.join(delaySeconds.value)
            });
        window.close();
    });
};

delaySeconds.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setDelay.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: In modern Chrome `alert` does nothing in inactive tabs. This is the intended behavior.

Comment: @wOxxOm it doesn't seem to work whether the new tab is the active one or not until I click on the extension icon for some reason.

Comment: it does work if the password is added dynamically. it just won't work on a new tab. its as though the extension isn't really active until i click on the extension, but after that i can refresh the tab, and when a password field is added dynamically it will produce the alert message.

Comment: Ah, you'll have to add `<all_urls>` to "permissions" for automatic activation.

Comment: ahhh ill try that rn

Comment: @wOxxOm booom! that did it! thank you

Comment: @wOxxOm ill go upvote your top answer since this question was dumb

Comment: Thanks, but the question is not dumb. It's the documentation's fault.